# I can't link my CSS to my HTML and it is driving me crazy

Tags: html, css

I am trying to link my CSS file to my HTML code and I can't get it to work. I have one big folder for a practice project I am working on called "Larry's Lawn Care" in that folder there are two sub folders one called "HTML" and one called "CSS" where I have a file called "index.css"

```css
p{
     font-size: 900px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lary's Lawn Care</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css"/>
    </head>
    <p>Test</p>
</html>
```

I have tried linking using href="/CSS/index.css href="CSS/index.css" href="index.css" and href="/index.css" and none of them have worked

Comment: Well, what's your folder structure? What URL shows when you load your  HTML file in the browser?

Comment: Note that the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

If your html file in in the HTML folder, you have to give the full relative path to the CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/index.css"/>
```

Here the ".." before the CSS is saying "go one folder up", which would be your folder project that hold the HTML and CSS folders.

Here is what I think the structure of the project looks like:

- Larry's Lawn Care

  - HTML

    - index.html
  - CSS

    - index.css

Comment: _"in that folder there are two sub folders one called "HTML" and one called "CSS" where I have a file called "index.css""_ does that sound like they're in the same folder?

Comment: @connexo How does it sound like the HTML file and CSS file are located in the same folder??

Comment: It sounds like both ***folders*** are in the same folder.

Comment: They aren't saying that it sounds like they are in the same folder. Thats why you are navigating **UP** a directory and _then_ **DOWN** into the CSS directory to access your css file. If they were in the same directory it would be as simple as writing href="index.css"

Answer (score 0):

You have to move up the directory:

```
"../CSS/index.css"
```

Using `..` moves up one level in the current directory.